# Python regex match n lines after match

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I have a pattern that works fine on regexr.com with pcre but when I use it with python it doesn't match anything.
the pattern is:

```
.*(?<=RSA SHA256:).*(?:.*\n){3}.*
```

and it matches the data on the website but when I run this on my python script it doesn't.
The goal is to match  Accepted publickey and the next 3 lines. 
Thank you!

script below:

```
import re
Accepted_publickey=r'.*(?<=RSA SHA256:).*(?:.*\n){3}.*'
file=open('secure')
for items in file:
    re1=re.search(Accepted_publickey,items)
    if re1:
        print(re1.group())
```

The actual data is:

```
Oct 21 17:27:21 localhost sshd[19772]: Accepted publickey for vagrant from 192.168.2.140 port 54614 ssh2: RSA SHA256:uDsE4ecSD9ElWQ5Q0fdMsbqEzOe0Hszilv8xhU6dT6M
Oct 21 17:27:22 localhost sshd[19772]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user vagrant by (uid=0)
Oct 21 17:27:22 localhost sshd[19772]: User child is on pid 19774
Oct 21 17:27:22 localhost sshd[19774]: Starting session: shell on pts/2 for vagrant from 192.168.2.140 port 54614 id 0
```

Comment: what is your actual behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use a lookbehind, you could match the value.

To match the 3 following lines, you could switch the newline and `.*` to omit the last `.*`

```
^.*\bRSA SHA256:.*(?:\n.*){3}
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*\bRSA SHA256:.*` Match `RSA SHA256:` in the string preceded by a word boundary
- `(?:\n.*){3}` repeat 3 times a newline followed by matching any char except a newline 3 times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rnZdRB/1)

In your code you might use [read()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

```
import re

Accepted_publickey = r'^.*RSA SHA256:.*(?:.*\n){3}.*'
f = open('secure')
items = f.read()
re1 = re.search(Accepted_publickey, items, re.M)
if re1:
    print(re1.group())
```

Comment: Thank you and this was helpful but I'm not sure why when I run it it doesn't print anything. The pattern does work on regex demo.

Comment: I have updated the answer with `re.M` Can you check if it works? I run in on my local environment with a file called `secure` and your example data and I get the 4 lines.

Comment: @J0876car That enables multiline. You can use `re.M` or `re.MULTILINE`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE and influences the meaning of the anchors.

Comment: Hi so as I was working more with this I noticed and it is just printing the first match of the line and the next 3 lines. What if I wanted to print all matches in the secure file and the next 3 lines? Thank you!

Comment: re2=re.findall(Accepted_publickey.strip(),items,re.M)
if re2:
    print('\n'',''\n'.join(re2)) and I get what I want. Thank you again!

Comment: @J0876car Indeed if you use re.findall you get all matches. There is also a code generator on regex101. This generates for example code using re.finditer https://regex101.com/r/Yl7cEF/1/codegen?language=python